# How to structure search result ranking data in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

What's the "best" way to structure scraped search result data in a Python? This will need to be stored so I can create graphs / plot trends for keyword ranking movement over time:

- keyword
- date/time of scraping round
- total number of search results found
- search result data (#1, #2, #3, etc.)

I'm thinking the following:

```
data = { 'keyword' : keyword,
          { 'datetime' : time.time(),
             { 'totalresults' : totalresults,
               '1': { 'title' : title, 'url' : url },
               '2': { 'title' : title, 'url' : url },
               '3': { 'title' : title, 'url' : url }
             }
          }
        }
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but I haven't used databases in projects yet. Some projects I've had developed use MongoDB, so I'll probably use that since I can peek in the code of these projects to see how things are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `search_results` a list instead of a dict indexed by sequential numbers. Your `totalresults` would then be redundant because it would just be the length of the `search_results` list.

```
data = {
    'keyword': keyword,
    'datetime': time.time(),
    'search_results': [
        {'title': title, 'url': url},
        {'title': title, 'url': url},
        {'title': title, 'url': url}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to save the data in the following format, if you are thinking of a single json(Table) object.

```
data = { 'keyword' : keyword,
         'datetime' : time.time(),
         'totalresults' : totalresults,
         'search_results': {
               '1': { 'title' : title, 'url' : url },
               '2': { 'title' : title, 'url' : url },
               '3': { 'title' : title, 'url' : url }
             }
        }
```

There are few problems if you are using the above format, say suppose the data of search result is huge, maybe 100000+ results, so the object size would be huge and hence which ever database you are using would have problem. I know mongoDB has 16MB limit. Same would be the case with other databases too.

To solve this problem you can split your data into multiple tables.
You can split it over different json(Table). Something like this

```
search_analytics = { 'id' : UUID,
                     'keyword' : keyword,
                     'datetime' : time.time() }

search_results = { 'search_id': reference to specific search request,
                   'search_results_details': {
                           'rank' : rank on which the search result appeared,
                           'title' : title,
                           'url' : url 
                       }
                 }
```

Example:

```
search_analytics = { 'id' : 12344-a12-123-123,
                     'keyword' : 'Beautiful',
                     'datetime' : time.time() }

search_results = { 'search_id': 12344-a12-123-123,
                   'search_results_details': {
                           'rank' : 1,
                           'title' : "Beautiful Mind",
                           'url' : 'https://example.com/a' 
                       }
                 }
search_results = { 'search_id': 12344-a12-123-123,
                   'search_results_details': {
                           'rank' : 2,
                           'title' : "Beautiful Soul",
                           'url' : 'https://example.com/b' 
                       }
                 }
search_results = { 'search_id': 12344-a12-123-123,
                   'search_results_details': {
                           'rank' : 1,
                           'title' : "Beautiful House",
                           'url' : 'https://example.com/c' 
                       }
                 }
```